# How to find the domain of long log functions?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I'm looking to know how to find the domain of log functions, combined with other things. I know that when considering domains, we can't allow $1/0$ (undefined), or the square root of a negative number. But I can't seem to work out where to start for this example.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2-x} + \ln(3+x(2-x))$$
I think so far I know that $x$ can never be $2$ because $1/(2-2)$ would be undefined. How do I do the next bit: $\ln(3+x(2-x))$?

Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: Hint: For real arguments and function values the argument of $\ln$  must be $>0.$ In your case you have to solve a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logarithmic functions do not admit negative arguments (if you are working in the real domain), so what you should do is to see for which values of x $3+x(2-x)>0$ so that you can find where the logarithm is defined.

The general domain for a logarithmic function $\ln{x}$ is $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks very much. So I found it can be -1 but not less than that, otherwise it will present a negative argument to the logarithmic function.

Comment: The argument of your log function is positive in the $(-1,3)$ domain, and as your first argument of the complete function is defined in all the reals except in the $x=2$ point, then the domain of your function is $(-1,2)\cup(2,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of a function made by combining several different functions are values of x that are in the domains of all the different functions-  the **intersection** of all the subfunctions.

Yes, $\frac{1}{2- x}$ has domain "all numbers except 2".  ln(x) has domain "all positive x", all x> 0, so "ln(3+ x(2- x))" has domain 3+ x(2- x)> 0.  That can be written as $x(3- x)> 3x- x^2> -3$ or $x^2- 3x< 3$ so $x^2- 3x- 3< 0$.  The equation $x^2- 3x- 3= 0$ has roots, by the quadratic formula, $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9+ 12}}{2}= \frac{3\pm\sqrt{21}}{2}$.  Since for x= 0, this is $0^2- 3(0)- 3= -3> 0$.  $x^2- 3x- 3< 0$ for all x $\frac{3- \sqrt{21}}{2}< x< \frac{3+ \sqrt{21}}{2}$. That includes x= 0 so we have to remove that and the domain of the original function is $\frac{3- \sqrt{21}}{2}< x< 0$ or $0< x< \frac{3+ \sqrt{21}}{2}$.

Comment: I think that you copied wrong the logarithm's argument to solve the inequality.